# Django REST Framework - Serialize nested relations on create

Tags: python, django, rest, frameworks, nested

I have those two seralizers based on following models:

```
class LanguageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Language
        fields = '__all__'


class GameSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    language = LanguageSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Game
        fields = '__all__'


class Game(models.Model):
    language = models.ForeignKey(Language)


class Language(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

When I try to create a new `Game` entity, I pass as parameter the `Language id` of this Game. For some reasons, DRF is expecting the language to be passed as a `dictionary` and not as an `integer`. Here is the error:

```
{
    "language": {
        "non_field_errors": [
            "Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got int."
        ]
    }
}
```

What is the proper way to indicate to DRF, to create a `Game` which has the `Language` property based on the provided `Language id` ?

Answer (score 1):

Creating a separate serializer that doesn't include all of the details about Language is one solution. You can create a separate serializer that uses the [`PrimaryKeyRelatedField()`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield)

```
# I always call mine shallow to differentiate between the full serializer
class ShallowGameSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    language = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField()
    class Meta:
        model = Game
        fields = '__all__'
```

You can use the normal `GameSerializer` when returning/listing objects, and then the `ShallowGameSerializer` when creating a Game, allowing you to just provide the id.